# Is it possible to update multiple documents with an increasing order in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

I have an array of document ids. The array is ordered and I want to update a fied `order`of all matching documents. The value of `order` should be the position in the array.

Currently I do the following which works fine:

```
const result = await this.collection.bulkWrite(
      orderedIncices.map((_id, index: number) => ({
        updateOne: {
          filter: { _id },
          update: { $set: { order: index } },
        },
      })),
    );
```

I'm wondering if there is a more efficient way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Updated as suggested in the comments.

Your approach is still good but you can also use the ***update*** function.

```
.update({
      _id: {
         $in: orderedIndexes
      }
    },
    [
        {
            $set: {
                order: {
                    $indexOfArray: [orderedIndices, "$_id"]
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    {
        multi: true
    }
)
```

*Note how in this case **$indexOfArray** is used to find the index of the **_id** of each document in the ***orderedIndices*** array and it is this **_id** value that is then used to update the related order field.*

Comment: You need to make this an update with aggregation pipeline in order to evaluate the expression, see https://mongoplayground.net/p/gNNHjYtAO5y

Comment: I've added the filter that I left out of the sample.